# Ubuntu server mount device issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, disk-space-utilization

i have ubuntu server and can not figure out with my space

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  7.8G     0 100% /
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           746M  180K  745M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       414G  1.7G  391G   1% /mnt
overflow        1.0M  4.0K 1020K   1% /tmp
```

I want to use the device mounted on /mnt as my primary one, because I'm running out of space. But i don't know what /dev/xvda1 is stands for, any suggestions?

Maybe i can resize device mounted on `/`? How to do so?

Comment: About xvda: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166083/what-is-the-dev-xvda1-device

Comment: And here you have information about resizing xen disks: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device `xvda1` is a partition on a virtual hard disk, the equivalent of `sda1`.

- `xvd` indicates a Xen virtual block device, while `sd` would be a physical disk.
- `a` indicates the first disk
- `1` indicates the first partition on the disk.

Broadly speaking, you can't do anything to your main boot partition - resize it, replace it etc - while you're booted from it.

I'm guessing this is a virtual machine on EC2? If so, be careful of using `xvdb` because it's probably [ephemeral storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), which will disappear next time you reboot. You can use it for temporary files, log files etc, but it would be a very bad idea to use it for your actual data.

To expand the space on `xvda1`, you'll need to shut the machine down and edit its storage settings in the AWS console.